# Python - sending number to the COM port

Tags: python, serial-port

I want to send a number to the COM port every second.
I created a pair of ports (COM3 and COM4) using the com0com program

It then tries to send the number 21 to the COM4 port.

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> ser= serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=1)
>>> ser.write(21)
```

but the operation hangs, does anyone know why this happens?
I'm definitely doing something wrong.
Maybe someone knows what needs to be done to make it work.

Comment: The argument passed to the write() function should be a *bytes* object (or similar) see [the documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)

Comment: "*I want to send a number ...*" - Unfortunately that's an ambiguous statement. In the context of computer programming, there are many forms to represent and transmit a "*number*". Some are oriented for use by computers, and others are for human readability. By "*number*", do you mean a binary value composed of one or more bytes in some endian order, or do you mean numeric ASCII characters (for some radix) that comprise a string? You have to answer these questions before it makes sense to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly, as -CtrlZ says you need to supply a *bytes* object – so for example *bytes([21])* rather than *21*. But even with this, your code can still hang depending on the serial device connected to your port. This can be fixed by changing the timeout parameter. *timeout* relates to the timeout of the port read operation. What you want is *write_timeout*. If you set this to zero, then the call returns correctly from your write operation, seemingly regardless of the state of the serial device attached to the port.

The code below sends a byte of value 65 (ASCII ‘A’ so that I could read it at the other end) once a second for 5 seconds, and reports back from the call as each byte is sent. I have confirmed that this works by connecting the port to an Arduino comms tester lash-up, and the bytes are indeed sent.

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, write_timeout=0)

bytes_object = bytes([65])

for a in range(5):
    bytes_sent = ser.write(bytes_object)
    print(f"Sent {bytes_sent} bytes")
    time.sleep(1)

ser.close()

print("done")
```

Just replace the 65 with 21.